# Play sound on rollover of all buttons in movie

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, user-interface, audio, rollover

I thought this would be a very basic thing to do but I've Googled myself in to a corner. I simply want a sound to play every time a button type element is hovered on, regardless of the button's position, rooting, parent, name, instance name, etc.

The sound file is in the library with the class/linkage "sroll" (Sound Rollover) and I use the following method to play all the other sounds:

```
MovieClip(root).audio_channel_c = MovieClip(root).snd8.play(0,1);
```

In my mind I'm looking for something along the lines of:

```
public button.eventlistener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, function(){
    MovieClip(root).audio_channel_c = MovieClip(root).snd10.play(0,1);
});
```

I'm working in AS3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more searching I found a rather crude way to do this. The listener picks up what's under the cursor at each pixel movement. If the pixel under the cursor is a SimpleButton of object class it determines if the mouse is still moving on a button it already entered. If it's a fresh enter it traces.

The result is a trace every time the cursor enters a button, but not as you scroll over the button. It also works on every instance of every button throughout the entire stage.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.SimpleButton;
import flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName;

function getClass(obj:Object):Class {
    return Class(getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName(obj)));
}

var last_button_to_mouse = "";

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, handle_custom_event, true);
function handle_custom_event(e:Event):void
{
    if(getQualifiedClassName(e.target)!="flash.display::SimpleButton"){
        last_button_to_mouse = ""
    }

    if(getQualifiedClassName(e.target)=="flash.display::SimpleButton" && (e.target.name != last_button_to_mouse)){
        last_button_to_mouse = e.target.name;

        trace("Place your script here for when the mouse enters any button on the stage");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, because I'm a complete idiot, and can't believe I didn't see a clear answer to this online, is if all the buttons are instances of one core button (like mine are) when you've clicked on the "OVER" frame the properties gives you the option for what sound should be made....